# How to show box after submit value in form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, function

So I have pop-up window where user need to enter name, after clicking submit button this window close.

You can test it here: http://eurokos.lt/under20/button.php (Click 21 button, then try to enter any value and see what happens)

For this pop-up box I've used function:

```
function popUp() {
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
}
```

This function is used for X button to close window:

```
function closeWindow() {
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
}
```

My button which open pop-up window looks like:

`Echo "<input type='button' onclick='popUp();' value='".$i."' />";`

And here is PHP_SELF and form:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "</br>You have entered: <b> $name </b>";

}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

`

What I need to do that posted result what entered and window not closed? 
Maybe I need to use popUp() function again when submitting? But how to do that correctly? Thank you.

Comment: FYI: `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` is open to XSS, remove it if your posting back to the same page E.G `action=""`

Comment: Thank you for reply, just tried, but the same, window closing.

Comment: If you submit the page will refresh. Better use `onsubmit` event and then display the entered name..

Comment: @Joke_Sense10 Thank you for reply, where I need to use `onsubmit`? on `action="onsubmit"`?

Comment: If I use `<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="name">` the same happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**html:**

```
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return display()">
<div id="answer"></div>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

**javascript:**

```
function display(){
 var ans    =   document.getElementById("name").value
 document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="You have entered:"+ans;
 return false;
}
```

**Update:**

```
 function popUp(){
 document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=""; //Add these in your popup function
 document.getElementById("name").value="";
 }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked for me! Possible to make that after user closed pop-up window and opened again data will be cleared? For now If I close and open It again, still is data entered, which I entered before.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but in placeholder still keep the word, I've tried to use `placeholder="Word...", but the same, after I close and again open pop-up window It shows last word which I entered

Comment: I din get you..You want the word to displayed on placeholder??

Comment: I want to remove word from placeholder after I close and open the pop-up window

Answer (score 0):

First of all i suggest you to avoid PHP_SELF in the action it can be manipulated by people and it's not good.

at top of page try to do :

```
<?php
 $thispage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>
<html>
.
.
.
 <form method="post" action="<?=$thispage?>">
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
 </form>
</html>
```

Then, using the action for sending data to PHP, will reload the page so you are probabilly losing all the inline fix you did.
Try to get the input values after the submit, assign them to varibles and do, for example:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","<?=$thispage?>",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("name=name");
```

with an asynchronous call you don't reload the page and you don't lost your changes